# How to filter the values in a dataframe where a column having list of strings as value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
        domain          intents  expressionId                     name
0           []               []             8  When I dare to be powerful – to use my strengt...
1           []               []             7  When one door of happiness closes, another ope...
2           []               []             6  The first step toward success is taken when yo...
3           []               []             5                  Get busy living or get busy dying
4  [financial, education]    [resolutions]  4  You know you’re in love when you can’t fall as...
5  [financial, business]     [materialistic]3                         Honesty is the best policy
```

Here is my dataframe which is having the domain column with list of strings. And, what I want is to fetch only rows that are having
'domain' contains 'financial'(domain==financial), so that I get the below results:

```
        domain          intents  expressionId                     name
4  [financial, education]    [resolutions]  4  You know you’re in love when you can’t fall as...
5  [financial, business]     [materialistic]3                         Honesty is the best policy
```

What I have tried so far is with the below command:

```
df['domain'].map(lambda x: 'financial' in x)
```

This is returning, the column with objectType as 'bool'.

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5     True
Name: domain, dtype: bool
```

But what I want is the filtered result not the bool values.

Please help me with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
dfFinaicals = df[df['domain'].map(lambda x: 'financial' in x)]
```

This is just asking the domain and using it to select the rows.  You were almost there.

```
dfFinaicals = df[df['domain'].contains('financial')]
```

is more elegant

Comment: First approach worked for me. Getting error for second one. AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'contains'

Answer (score 1):

df[df.domain.apply(lambda v: 'financial' in v)]

df.domain.contains('financial') didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Without actually trying to make your dataframe, I would suggest:

```
new_df = old_df[old_df['domain'] == 'financial']
```

Comment: I don't know why it didn't write it in code format, just eliminate the ''' '''.

Comment: im getting empty Dataframe for this approach.